# Creating line from polygon shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, expression, geometry-generator

I have a shapefile of an airport that outlines the runway area. I want to take this shapefile with the runway area and create a single line that extends out 5-10 miles out each direction. I have tried extracting the nodes and I have tried to convert to lines.

The photo you will see the shapefile in yellow and the desired effect is in red

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this expression with [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) ([see here for details about these two options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)). The value `10000` is the length of the line to both sides form the centroid of the polygon: change this value if needed:

```
extend (
    make_line (
        centroid ($geometry),
        project (
            centroid($geometry),
            10000,
            radians(main_angle( $geometry))
        )
    ), 
    10000, 
    0
)
```

*The solution using Geometry generator*
[image]